# IE11: Allow display of local HTML files

Tags: security, group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2, internet-explorer-10

How can I enable Internet Explorer 11 that has Enhanced Protected Mode turned on to display local HTML files?

This is very annoying also I see the security need behind this feature. Can someone please point me in the right direction here?

**[Addendum]**

If I unlink all exsiting GPOs containing IE settings I am able to open up a local html file. So the culprit is some of our GPO settings. The challenge is now to find the relevant one... any idea's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GPO setting which was preventing the display of local html files was:

```
User => Policies => Administrative Templates => Windows Components => Internet Explorer => Security Features => Local Machine Zone Lockdown Security => Internet Explorer Process
```

If the above is set to **disabled** IE won't display local html files, which means unsetting or enabling it made it work.

Answer (score 1):

The IE Internals blog discusses it thoroughly [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2012/06/20/loading-local-files-in-enhanced-protected-mode-in-internet-explorer-10.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/03/23/understanding-local-machine-zone-lockdown-restricted-this-webpage-from-running-scripts-or-activex-controls.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for adding the first link; I was looking all over for why my local file was no longer working in IE from the disk, but working fine from SharePoint. Adding `<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->` solved it for me